# UIButton in a subview, trigger action in current ViewController

Tags: iphone, uibutton, target, self

I have a problem. I've a normal viewcontroller where I add UITextViews in a scrollview. To these UITextviews I add a dynamic number of UIButtons, to which I want to add a target. The reason I add them to the UITextViews is that adding them to the viewcontroller adding the text view's origin will make them end up outside the screen and not scroll, of course. But when I do that, the buttons trigger the action.

My question is: how do I specify the viewcontroller as target? Using self or using the var created in the appdelegate as target does not trigger it. If "two superlevels up from the textview" will work I will use that, just don't know how to specify it correctly.

My code:

```
   UIImage *img=[UIImage imageNamed:@"phonebutton40x30.png"];
   UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
   [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(phoneemail:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   [btn setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   btn.tag=700+i;
   btn.frame=CGRectMake(xoffs+3, yoffs+19, 50, 38);
   [tvMain addSubview:btn];
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you are asking? Does it work as expected when you add your buttons to `[self.view addSubview:btn]` but not when you add it to `tvMain`? That is, does it work if you just change the line `[tvMain addSubview:btn]` to `[self.view addSubview:btn]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it back then by adding the buttons to the scrollview instead of the textview.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove colon from your code

`[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(phoneemail:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`

The corrected one is 

`[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(phoneemail) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`

If I guess, this will probably help you.

Comment: No, afaik the colon is there for methods, gone for functions. (Methods might not require colons.) As I said it worked with the exact same code when I made it a subview of the navigated-to viewcontroller, instead of the UITextView.